# I can't expose my response header using CORS

Tags: http, angular, cors

I am currently using angular2 to retrieve a JWT token from my API. The API is generating and responding with the token perfectly, it stores the token  in the response header.

I can clearly see that the token exist using postman or my chrome network response header tab but my angular2 can't. I currently have this code in my angular 2 app to help expose it but I still can't see it.

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE';
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'token'
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'
'Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'token'
```

Comment: These headers need to be added on the response by the server not on the client.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I do believe I am exposing it correctly from my server. `CORS(allow_all_origins=True, allow_all_headers=True, allow_all_methods=True);`. This is Python / falcon_cors 1.0.0

Comment: Which server has the "Access-Control" flags set?  CORS is designed to allow Cross Origin.  If I understand correctly you have your Python Server *and* a remote server you are getting a JSON Web Token from.  It's the remote server that's serving up the tokens you need the headers set on.  If I'm misunderstanding and you've only got one server you don't need CORS.